# Express.js and MongoDB: PUT request to nested object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to make a PUT request to update the data of individual items, which each comprises one MongoDB document. It works fine for all keys, except for the `socialLinks` key, which consists of the objects `twitter`, `facebook` and `instagram`.

I'm able to post the data to these object just fine using this code:

```
router.post(
  '/',
  [
    auth,
    [
      check('itemName', 'Name is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('companyName', 'Company name is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('thumbnailFileName', 'Thumbnail is required').isURL(),
      check('tagline', 'Tagline is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('description', 'Description is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('topics', 'At least one topic is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('website', 'At least one topic is required').isURL(),
      check('availability', 'Availability is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('socialLinks.twitter', 'Please enter a valid URL').isURL(),
      check('socialLinks.facebook', 'Please enter a valid URL').isURL(),
      check('socialLinks.instagram', 'Please enter a valid URL').isURL()
    ]
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    const {
      itemName,
      companyName,
      thumbnailFileName,
      tagline,
      description,
      topics,
      website,
      availability,
      makers,
      socialLinks: { twitter, facebook, instagram }
    } = req.body;

    try {
      const newItem = new Item({
        user: req.user.id,
        itemName,
        companyName,
        thumbnailFileName,
        tagline,
        description,
        topics,
        website,
        availability,
        makers,
        socialLinks: { twitter, facebook, instagram }
      });

      const item = await newItem.save();

      res.json(item);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  }
);
```

But I'm having some trouble with updating the `socialLinks` data with my PUT route:

```
router.put('/:id', auth, async (req, res) => {
  const {
    itemName,
    companyName,
    thumbnailFileName,
    tagline,
    description,
    topics,
    website,
    availability,
    makers,
    socialLinks
    // socialLinks: { twitter, facebook, instagram }
  } = req.body;

  // Build item object
  const itemFields = {};
  if (itemName) itemFields.itemName = itemName;
  if (companyName) itemFields.companyName = companyName;
  if (thumbnailFileName) itemFields.thumbnailFileName = thumbnailFileName;
  if (tagline) itemFields.tagline = tagline;
  if (description) itemFields.description = description;
  if (topics) itemFields.topics = topics;
  if (website) itemFields.website = website;
  if (availability) itemFields.availability = availability;
  if (makers) itemFields.makers = makers;
  if (socialLinks) itemFields.socialLinks = socialLinks;
  // if ({socialLinks: { twitter, facebook, instagram }}) itemFields.socialLinks[{socialLinks: { twitter, facebook, instagram }}] = {socialLinks: { twitter, facebook, instagram }};

  try {
    let item = await Item.findById(req.params.id);

    if (!item) return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Item not found' });

    // Make sure user owns item
    if (item.user.toString() !== req.user.id) {
      return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Not authorized' });
    }

    item = await Item.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      { $set: itemFields },
      { new: true }
    );

    res.json(item);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

I've tried all kinds of combinations to make it work. In the PUT route, if I destructure only `socialLinks` and in `itemFelds` only include `if (socialLinks) itemFields.socialLinks = socialLinks;`, then I'm able to change one or more `socialLinks` simultaneously, but if I don't include all `socialLinks`, then the ones I didn't include in my PUT request are deleted.

Mongoose schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    refer: 'users'
  },
  itemName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  companyName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  thumbnailFileName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  tagline: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  topics: [
    {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  ],
  website: {
    type: String
  },
  availability: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  makers: [
    {
      type: String
    }
  ],
  socialLinks: {
    twitter: {
      type: String
    },
    facebook: {
      type: String
    },
    instagram: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('item', ItemSchema);
```

Comment: have you tried `= {socialLinks: { twitter || null, facebook || null, instagram || null}`

Comment: I tried, VScode highlights it as incompatible, and it doesn't work unfortunately.